# Mencoder subtitle problem

Tags: mencoder, subtitle

I want to include subtitle to a avi file with mencorder. Mencoder is starting to encode but subtitle does not appeaer in new file. Here is my mencoder code

```
/usr/local/bin/mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -sub "mov.srt" -o "Domino_with_subs.avi" "mov.avi"
```

Comment: i had the same problem, did you solve it yet?

Comment: You can try [this][1] solution.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76202/how-to-burn-subtitle-to-avi/76348#76348

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set the video codec to by copied... To be able to add subtitle mencoder needs to re-encode the video.

This will work

```
/usr/local/bin/mencoder -oac copy -ovc lavc -sub "mov.srt" -o "Domino_with_subs.avi" "mov.avi"
```